# Adding header & footer to each page

Tags: html, node.js

I want to add a header and footer to each page. I tried with jQuery but it didn't work for me. I use nodeJS in the backend. Do you have any suggestion so that there will be no problem with the server?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried with php and jQuery but couldn't get what I wanted. I will do it in nodeJs

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with html **iframes** but its not recommended.

```
<iframe src="myURL" width="300" height="300">Browser not compatible.</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 divs and request them in every page?